# How can I use Azerbaijani characters?

Tags: characters

I want to know how can we ıntroduce new character especıally  `ə` character. In other words I want to learn how can we use Azerbaijani characters (letters) in LATEX.(Miktex+texmaker) Turkish characters are not sufficient.

Comment: **Welcome.** Please provide a complete but minimal code example.

Comment: And please also state which compiler you're using and if you were able/willing to switch.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Use a unicode engine (LuaTeX/XeTeX) and the right font.

Answer (score 4):

Since the character Əə is borrowed from Cyrillic, we can do the same

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[X2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{Ə}{\textazeriSchwa}
\newunicodechar{ə}{\textazerischwa}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\textazeriSchwa}{%
  {\fontencoding{X2}\selectfont\symbol{"9A}}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textazerischwa}{%
  {\fontencoding{X2}\selectfont\symbol{"BA}}%
}

\makeatletter
\expandafter\def\expandafter\@uclclist\expandafter
  {\@uclclist\textazerischwa\textazeriSchwa}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Aa, Bb, Cc, Çç, Dd, Ee, Əə, Ff, Gg, Ğğ, Hh, Xx, Iı, İi, Jj, Kk, 
Qq, Ll, Mm, Nn, Oo, Öö, Pp, Rr, Ss, Şş, Tt, Uu, Üü, Vv, Yy, Zz

\textit{%
  Aa, Bb, Cc, Çç, Dd, Ee, Əə, Ff, Gg, Ğğ, Hh, Xx, Iı, İi, Jj, Kk, 
  Qq, Ll, Mm, Nn, Oo, Öö, Pp, Rr, Ss, Şş, Tt, Uu, Üü, Vv, Yy, Zz
}

\textbf{%
  Aa, Bb, Cc, Çç, Dd, Ee, Əə, Ff, Gg, Ğğ, Hh, Xx, Iı, İi, Jj, Kk, 
  Qq, Ll, Mm, Nn, Oo, Öö, Pp, Rr, Ss, Şş, Tt, Uu, Üü, Vv, Yy, Zz
}

\MakeUppercase{%
  Aa, Bb, Cc, Çç, Dd, Ee, Əə, Ff, Gg, Ğğ, Hh, Xx, Iı, İi, Jj, Kk, 
  Qq, Ll, Mm, Nn, Oo, Öö, Pp, Rr, Ss, Şş, Tt, Uu, Üü, Vv, Yy, Zz
}

\MakeLowercase{%
  Aa, Bb, Cc, Çç, Dd, Ee, Əə, Ff, Gg, Ğğ, Hh, Xx, Iı, İi, Jj, Kk, 
  Qq, Ll, Mm, Nn, Oo, Öö, Pp, Rr, Ss, Şş, Tt, Uu, Üü, Vv, Yy, Zz
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One alternative is `\textschwa` of package `tipa`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
\textschwa
\end{document}
```

The other symbols can be used directly with  `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` for `pdflatex`. You can also use "ə" directly with   `newunicodechar` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ə}{\textschwa}
\begin{document}

ş ğ ü ç ı a ə

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to official documentation you can use Azerbaijani language:

```
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[azerbaijani]{babel}
```

Perhaps many fonts may not include Azerbaijani letters such as ə, ü, ğ, etc. Personally I use "Times New Roman".

https://ctan.org/pkg/babel-azerbaijani?lang=en